# How do I get code to read both first and last and values of a randomly generated array?

Tags: c++

I was debugging my code when I realized my code constantly reads the same thing for one one function; it only reads the last value of an array. I want it to read both the first and the last value of the array. I've tried many methods only to have it read the same thing. How do I fix this?
Point of emphasis is below.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const unsigned int sizeofArray = 6;
    int arraysize[sizeofArray];

    // Get an array
    cout << "Generated Array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
    {
        arraysize[i] = rand() % 50;
        cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
    cout << " \n";

    // Only first and last element (fix) // READ HERE ISSUE IS HERE
    cout << "First and last element: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
    {
        arraysize[i = 0] && arraysize[i = 5];
        cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // Every element at an odd index
    cout << "Every element at an odd index: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // Every odd element
    cout << "Every odd element: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
    {
        if (arraysize[i] % 2 == 1)
            cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";


    // All elements in reverse order
    cout << "All elements in reverse order:";
    for (int i = sizeofArray - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `arraysize[i = 0] && arraysize[i = 5];` is supposed to achieve. What it does achieve is precisely the same as plain `i = 5;` If you want to print the first and the last element, that would be `cout << " " << arraysize[0] << " " << arraysize[sizeofArray-1];` - you don't need a loop for that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hi Igor. I've tried your suggestion and I got what I wanted but I also got the two numbers mashed together as part of the output before they are both read.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Update your question to show the code you are compiling now, what output you expect, and what you observe instead. Prepare a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the rest of the code to understand it a little bit more. By calling the for-loop the first time the following happens:

`arraysize[i = 0] && arraysize[i = 5];`

First you are setting i to 0 and `arraysize[i = 0]` returns the first element. Than you are setting i to 5 and `arraysize[i = 5]` returns the fifth element of the array. The logical and (&&) compares now the first and the fifth element of the array. If both are bigger than 0 the result is 1 (true) otherwise it is 0 (false). But nothing happens with it. You get the same result by writing `i = 0; i = 5; 1;` or `i = 0; i = 5; 0;` .

Now you are calling `cout << " " << arraysize[i];` which writes the fifth element on the console. By returning to the for-loop i is 5 and `i < sizeofArray` is false (0) and the loop stops.

Easiest way to do it would be:

```
cout << "First and last element: ";
cout << " " << arraysize[0] << " " << arraysize[sizeofArray - 1] << " \n";

// Every element at an odd index
```

Or if you really want to iterate over the array (no need for it):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || i == sizeofArray - 1) {
        cout << " " << arraysize[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, and you certainly don't need the `&&` operator. Just access the items with array indexing:

```cpp
cout << arraysize[0] << ' ' << arraysize[5];
```